# Reading of 摘み in this sentence

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

> ぱっと出て、薬草を摘み、すぐに戻ってくればいい。

Is 摘み read here as つみ or つまみ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would read it as つみ.

摘{つ}む here means "to pick (e.g. flowers)", so「薬草を摘{つ}む」＝ "to pick medicinal herbs". つまむ could *technically* be used here as well (if the person ate the herbs like they were snacks after picking them up, or if they just went out to pinch the herbs with their fingers), but it's usually written in hiragana, so if there are no other indications, you would never expect to read 摘む as つまむ.

If you run into similar cases, you can e.g. check if the dictionary entries have a「▽」 or a「×」next to the kanji, which would indicate non-常用 usage. As you can see on [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%91%98%E3%82%80-572455), in this case, these has been added next to all of the kanji versions of つまむ.